# Excel 2007 COUNTIF in even rows only

Tags: arrays, string, excel, countif

I have an array of cells (C2:D43) in which I want to count the number of times a particular string ("filler") occurs. However, I only want to consider the even rows in my array (so basically, the array is C2:D2;C4:D4, etc.). How can I do this? I'm working with Excel 2007.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `SUMPRODUCT` formula will do it:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:D43="filler")*(MOD(ROW(C2:D43),2)=0))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `MOD(ROW(),2)=0` to split up your cells so that your array has two sets: even and odd cells. Then find a way to tell Excel to choose only the values that are the opposite value of the one evaluated at the first row of the array.  I'll see if I can find a way to formalize this.

Comment: `Row()` in this case tests whether the row containing the formula is even. That's not what the OP is requesting.

Comment: @Doug Ah, you're right.  I've edited my answer to describe something closer to reality.